# Cannot bind l-value to fowarding reference

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding-reference

I've got a template class that holds n number of T's using variadic templates parameters and recursive inheritance. This is rather like a Tuple and so that's how I've named it here:

```
template<class T, size_t tupleSize>
class MyTuple : private MyTuple<T, tupleSize - 1> {
private:
    T t;
public:
    MyTuple(std::string name)
            : t(name),
              MyTuple<T, tupleSize - 1>(name) {}
};

template<class T>
class MyTuple<T, 0> {
public:
    MyTuple(std::string name) {}
};
```

I'm now attempting to create a CompositeTuple class that allows multiple MyTuple objects to be strung together. This is intended to hold either instances of MyTuple object, or references to MyTuple objects, the usage is intended to be something like:

```
struct A {
    A(std::string s) {}
};

int main() {
    MyTuple<A, 3> a("hello");

    CreateCompositeTuple(a, MyTuple<A, 1>("world"));

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately my current implementation of CompositeTuple is falling short of the mark:

```
template<class ...T>
class CompositeTuple;

template<>
class CompositeTuple<> {
};

template<template<class T, size_t tupleSize> class TupleType, size_t tupleSize, class T, class ...TupleTypes>
class CompositeTuple<TupleType<T, tupleSize>, TupleTypes...>
        : private CompositeTuple<TupleTypes...> {
private:
    const TupleType<T, tupleSize> tuple;
public:
    CompositeTuple(TupleType<T, tupleSize> &&tuple, TupleTypes &&...tuples)
            : CompositeTuple<TupleTypes...>(tuples...),
              tuple(std::forward<TupleType<T, tupleSize>>(tuple)) {}
};



template<template<class T, size_t tupleSize> class ...TupleType, size_t ...tupleSize, class ...T>
auto CreateCompositeTuple(TupleType<T, tupleSize> &&...tuples) {
    return CompositeTuple<TupleType<T, tupleSize>...>(std::forward<TupleType<T, tupleSize>...>(tuples...));
}
```

The invocation of CreateCompositeTuple generates the following compiler error: `error: cannot bind 'MyTuple' lvalue to 'MyTuple&&'`

What am I doing wrong here? Though I've not been able to solve the problem, obviously, all the reading I've done suggests that this should be possible.

**Edit:**
I need to have further methods in CompositeTuple that has access to both the T and tupleSize template arguments. Something like this:

```
template<size_t index, typename std::enable_if<index < tupleSize>::type * = nullptr>
constexpr const T &At() const {
    return tuple.At<index>();
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Attempting to add a templated constructor as per Igor's suggesting:

```
// ...
template<template<class T, size_t tupleSize> class TupleType, size_t tupleSize, class T, class ...TupleTypes>
class CompositeTuple<TupleType<T, tupleSize>, TupleTypes...>
        : private CompositeTuple<TupleTypes...> {
private:
    const TupleType<T, tupleSize> tuple;
public:        
    template<class TT, class ...TTs>
    CompositeTuple(TT &&tuple, TTs &&...tuples)
        : CompositeTuple<TTs...>(tuples...),
          tuple(std::forward<TT>(tuple)) {}
};

template<class ...TupleType>
auto CreateCompositeTuple(TupleType &&...tuples) {
    return CompositeTuple<TupleType...>(std::forward<TupleType>(tuples)...);
}
//...
```

I've now got an "invalid use of incomplete type" error inside the CreateCompositeTuple function.

Comment: `TupleType<T, tupleSize> &&` is an rvalue reference, not a universal reference (`T&&` would be a universal reference). Naturally, an lvalue cannot bind to an rvalue reference.

Comment: So to achieve my goals here am I going to have to introduce a template class that wraps CompositeTuple, and then specialise CompositeTuple for reference/non-reference values?

Comment: You could have a templated constructor that takes arbitrary types by universal reference, rather than `TupleType` specifically.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you, I was able to make the changes you suggested and get my initial example working, however I've edited the question with an additional requirement that I have for this CompositeTuple class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nature of the difficulty. `CompositeTuple` does take `T` and `tupleSize` as template parameters. What exactly is the problem with `At`?

Comment: Clearly my understanding is lacking here, I suspect the error mentioned in my latest edit is due to me not supplying tupleSize and T parameters in the class template parameters, but having to exclude them from the constructor and function templates leaves me confused as to where to go from here.

Comment: The problem is, the first `TupleType` in `CreateCompositeTuple` call is `MyTuple&` (a reference), so you are trying to instantiate `CompositeTuple<MyTuple&>`, which doesn't match specialization and tries to use the primary template instead. Make it `return CompositeTuple<typename std::decay<TupleType>::type...>(std::forward<TupleType>(tuples)...);` [Demo](http://rextester.com/UIJB55907)

Comment: Using std::decay precludes the tuple being stored as a reference, can this be solved in a different manner?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean, tuple being stored as a reference? Stored where and by whom?

Comment: In the CompositeTuple class there is a 'tuple' member of type TupleType<...>. Applying std::decay to the template arguments appears to force TupleType to be MyTuple<...> rather than MyTuple<...>&.

Comment: `TupleType` is a template template parameter of `CompositeTuple`. It can't possibly resolve to a reference, only to a class template. `CompositeTuple<AnyType&>` matches the primary template, not the specialization. Which is precisely why you are getting "incomplete type" error without `std::decay`.

Comment: Ok thank you. So back to my original ask: are you saying it's not possible and that I should move on with my life?

Comment: I suppose you could add another specialization, `template<template<class T, size_t tupleSize> class TupleType, ...>
class CompositeTuple<TupleType<T, tupleSize>&, TupleTypes...>` Note the ampersand.

Comment: Ah, fantastic, that's done the trick, thank you very much for all your help. If you'd like to post a summary of all this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.